# PostgreSQL - relation doesnt exist error when granting priviliges

Tags: postgresql

I entered postgres console with sudo and did this:

```
create user uu with password 'uu';    
create database u_db owner uu;   
grant all privileges on u_db to uu;
```

Error: Relation u_db doesnt exist.

Comment: `grant all privileges on DATABASE u_db to uu;` ([more info](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html))

Answer (score 32):

You have to use the keyword `DATABASE` for granting here. So I'm posting you the output from psql in:

```
postgres=# create user uu with password 'uu'; 
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# create database u_db owner uu;  
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# grant all privileges on u_db to uu;
FEHLER:  Relation »u_db« existiert nicht
postgres=# grant all privileges on database u_db to uu;
GRANT
```

However. IMHO through the owner setting of database you don't need to grant extra rights for the user `uu`.